# Check if at least one specific value exists looking through all inner arrays in an array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, frontend

I have the array **"arr"** which contains 2 objects and each object has the array **"innerArr"** which contains 2 or 3 objects with one value **"val"** for each object:

```js
let arr = [
  {
    innerArr: [
      { val: "Apple" },
      { val: "Grape" }
    ]
  },
  {
    innerArr: [
      { val: "Peach" },
      { val: "Mango" },
      { val: "Kiwi" }
    ]
  }
];
```

Now, I want to check if **at least one specific value like "Kiwi"** exists looking through **all inner arrays "innerArr"** in the array **"arr"**.

I created the code to check if **at least one specific value "Kiwi"** exists and it returns **"true"**.

```js
let result = false;

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].innerArr.length; j++) {
    if(arr[i].innerArr[j].val == "Kiwi") { // Check if "Kiwi" exists
      result = true;
    }
  }
}

console.log(result); // true
```

This is **the full runnable code**:

```js
let arr = [
  {
    innerArr: [
      { val: "Apple" },
      { val: "Grape" }
    ]
  },
  {
    innerArr: [
      { val: "Peach" },
      { val: "Mango" },
      { val: "Kiwi" }
    ]
  }
];

let result = false;

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].innerArr.length; j++) {
    if(arr[i].innerArr[j].val == "Kiwi") { // Check if "Kiwi" exists
      result = true;
    }
  }
}

console.log(result); // true
```

In addition, this is the case of **"Strawberry"** which returns **"false"**:

```js
let arr = [
  {
    innerArr: [
      { val: "Apple" },
      { val: "Grape" }
    ]
  },
  {
    innerArr: [
      { val: "Peach" },
      { val: "Mango" },
      { val: "Kiwi" }
    ]
  }
];

let result = false;

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].innerArr.length; j++) {
    if(arr[i].innerArr[j].val == "Strawberry") { // Check if "Strawberry" exists
      result = true;
    }
  }
}

console.log(result); // false
```

However, I want to make this code with **"Kiwi"** simpler. Are there any ways to make this code simpler?

```js
let result = false;

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].innerArr.length; j++) {
    if(arr[i].innerArr[j].val == "Kiwi") { // Check if "Kiwi" exists
      result = true;
    }
  }
}

console.log(result); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.some`

```js
let arr = [
  {
    innerArr: [
      { val: "Apple" },
      { val: "Grape" }
    ]
  },
  {
    innerArr: [
      { val: "Peach" },
      { val: "Mango" },
      { val: "Kiwi" }
    ]
  }
];

let fruit = "Kiwi"
let result = arr.some(({ innerArr }) => innerArr.some(({val}) => val === fruit))

console.log(result)
```

Its even faster then your loop because `.some` stops looping after it finds the searched result

Comment: Documentation on `some`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    innerArr: [
      { val: "Apple" },
      { val: "Grape" }
    ]
  },
  {
    innerArr: [
      { val: "Peach" },
      { val: "Mango" },
      { val: "Kiwi" }
    ]
  }
];

let fruits = arr.flatMap(e => e.innerArr).map(e => e.val)

console.log(fruits)
console.log(fruits.includes('Kiwi'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"some()" function**:

```js
let arr = [
  {
    innerArr: [
      { val: "Apple" },
      { val: "Grape" }
    ]
  },
  {
    innerArr: [
      { val: "Peach" },
      { val: "Mango" },
      { val: "Kiwi" }
    ]
  }
];

// Check if "Kiwi" exists
let result = arr.some(v1 => v1.innerArr.some(v2 => v2.val == "Kiwi"));
console.log(result); // true

// Check if "Strawberry" exists
result = arr.some(v1 => v1.innerArr.some(v2 => v2.val == "Strawberry"));
console.log(result); // false
```